# bootstrap's css file conflicts with other css files in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I wanted to use react-bootstrap in one of my pages, and I had to include the `bootstrap.min.css` file for it. I included using webpack (I'm using webpack for my app). But the rules in this css file are unnecessarily conflicting with other styles I've defined elsewhere. Is there any solution to avoid this conflict?

Comment: I haven't used React much but I'm guessing the rules of specificity still apply when it comes to how the styles are laid out. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 2):

Place `bootstrap.min.css` after `style.css` or which every style file you have created. This would solve the problem.